# Convexity of polynomials of odd degree

Tags: polynomials, convex-analysis

> Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function defined by a polynomial of degree $n \ge2$ with real coefficients (the
> function is convex on the whole $\mathbb{R}$). Prove that $n$ is an even number.

The question can be easily attacked by using the non-negativity of second derivatives of
convex functions. However, I failed to approach it from the contra-positive side; can we show (constructively) that there is always at least one inflection point in polynomials of odd ($n\ge 3$) degree? (preferably without using derivatives)

Comment: Why don’t you want to use derivatives? That seems like the simplest solution.

Comment: Also, please [edit] your post to define what you mean by "reflection point".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^d a_kx^k$, where $a_d\neq 0$ and $d\geqslant 3$ is odd. We consider the case $a_d>0$. We work by contradiction. Assume $f$ is convex.

First, by binomial theorem, note that $$(x+1)^k-x^k=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{k}{j}x^j=x^k=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{j}x^j,$$ which is a polynomial of degree $k-1$ and positive coefficients. Therefore $$f(x+1)-f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^d a_k[(x+1)^k-x^k]=\sum_{k=0}^d \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom{k}{j}a_kx^j.$$ This is a polynomial with degree $d-1$ (which is even and greater than $0$) and lead coefficient $\binom{d}{d-1}a_d=da_d>0$. So $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f(x+1)-f(x)=+\infty$. Therefore for a sufficiently large positive integer $N$, $$f(-N+1)-f(-N)>f(1)-f(0).\tag{1}$$

By convexity, for any $x$, $$f(x)=f\Bigl(\frac{x+1}{2}+\frac{x-1}{2}\Bigr)\leqslant \frac{f(x+1)}{2}+\frac{f(x-1)}{2}.$$ Multiplying both sides by $2$ and subtracting $f(x)+f(x-1)$ yields that $$f(x)-f(x-1)\leqslant f(x+1)-f(x).\tag{2}$$  Repeated applications of $(2)$ yield that $f(-N+k+1)-f(-N+k)$ is a non-decreasing function of $k$. Applying this with $k=0$ and $k=N$ yields that $$f(-N+1)-f(-N)\leqslant f(1)-f(0),$$ contradicting $(1)$.

The case $a_d<0$ is similar, except $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x+1)-f(x)=-\infty$. So $f(N+1)-f(N)<f(1)-f(0)$ for some large positive integer $N$. But this again contradicts repeated applications of $(2)$, which is unchanged by the sign of $a_d$.

I've avoided derivatives, but it's essentially the same geometric argument, but we're using the discrete derivative $\frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{1}$. Convexity yields that this is non-decreasing, but it's a non-constant polynomial of even degree, which cannot be non-decreasing.